# Property of a subgroup of a direct product

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G = A \times B$ is a finite group. For convenience, we will view this as the internal direct product of $A$ and $B$. Let $H \leq G$ ans suppose that $H$ satisfies the following conditions:

(a) $H \unlhd \pi_A(H) \times \pi_B(H)$;

(b) Whenever $H \leq K \unlhd L \leq G$ such that $K = \pi_A(K) \times \pi_B(K)$ and $L =\pi_A(L) \times \pi_B(L)$, then $L = N_L(H)K$.

> I need to show that $H$ satisfies the above conditions in $A \times N_B(\pi_B(H))$.

For condition (a), we have that $\pi_{N_B(\pi_B(H))}(H) \leq \pi_B(H)$, and so $\pi_A(H) \times \pi_{N_B(\pi_B(H))}(H) \leq \pi_A(H) \times \pi_B(H)$. Moreover, it is clear that $H \leq \pi_A(H) \times \pi_{N_B(\pi_B(H))}(H)$. Since $H \unlhd \pi_A(H) \times \pi_B(H)$, we have that $H \unlhd \pi_A(H) \times \pi_{N_B(\pi_B(H))}(H)$.

I'm not sure how to proceed in proving condition (b) holds with respect to $A \times N_B(\pi_B(H))$

Comment: What are $\pi_A$, $\pi_B$, $N_B$, $N_L$ and so on?

Comment: $\pi_A $ and $\pi_B$ are the projection map i.e. $\pi_A : A \times B \to A$, and $N_B( \pi_B(H)$ is the normalizer of $\pi_B(H)$ in $B$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by Condition (b) holds with respect to ...  You seem to have assume that Condition (b) holds already. Could you write down exactly what it is you are trying to prove.